# Storing each character from text file

Tags: c, string, file

First, Sorry I'm not good in using english

THIS MY OUTPUT

```
you just read : abcdefg4523 hij

you just read : 234kl  monp

you just read : qrs tuv

you just read : wx 452 z

This file have 4 alphabets
```

Last line counts the lines I have instead

I want to count only the alphabet and that my output would print  "This file have 26 alphabets" (see my file at the bottom)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define INPUT "file.txt"
#define MAX 1024
int main(void)
{
    FILE *pIn;
    int count = 0 ;
    char inputBuffer[MAX];
    char alphabet[MAX];
    pIn=fopen(INPUT,"r");
    while (fgets(inputBuffer,sizeof(inputBuffer),pIn) != NULL)
    {
        printf("you just read : %s",inputBuffer);
        count++;
    }
    fclose(pIn);
    printf("\nThis file have %d alphabets\n",count);
    return 0;

}
```

ABOUT MY FILE.txt:

```
abcdefg4523 hij

234kl  monp

qrs tuv

wx 45y2 z
```

Comment: Outstanding. Be sure and tip your server.

Comment: Son you will need to improve that english if you expect someone to understand what you want.

Comment: #Havenard sorry about that. i'm south-asian, i will improve my english :)

Comment: Your program seems to be working fine. It reads in lines from a file, prints them out and then says how many lines there were. Is it supposed to be doing something else too? What is the array `char alphabet[MAX];` for?

Comment: #squeamish ossifrage
I want to counting only the alphabets in this file

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. You want to count up the number of alphabetic characters ('a'..'z') that appear in the input, is that right? Try using the `isalpha()` function inside a loop with each input string.

Comment: isalpha() is a function in the Standard C Library.  "The isalpha() function returns zero if the character tests false and returns non-zero if the character tests true."  You need to loop through each character in the inputBuffer, calling is alpha() on each character.  Something like: `alphaCharacterCount += isalpha(inputbuffer[i])`

Comment: Any particular reason for the de-accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the point @Barbiyong. You want to count the number of alphabet characters in the input file you are passing. But for that functionality why are you making use of fgets() function? As the function name itself says, it will read the input as a string and output it. There is another function called fgetc() for that. Refer to the code below for your understanding and make changes accordingly.

```
c=fgetc(pIn);
if isaplpha(c)
{
  printf("Encountered alphabet:%c",char(c));
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`getc()` or `fgetc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) and check if [`isalpha()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html).

```
int c;
size_t count = 0;

...

c = fgetc(filehandle)
if (isalpha(c))
    ++count;
```

---

If the input can be wide bytes, you could use [`fgetwc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetwc.3.html) instead and check by [`iswalpha()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iswalpha.3.html).

Then you also have to ensure that [locale is set](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Or you could check the upper bits if you only want to count length of all characters.

```
if ((c & 0xc0) != 0x80) 
    ...
```

---

Another way could be to use an array to collect stats, and calculate/check things afterward.

E.g. ([ASCII only](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_stats(unsigned int cc[256])
{
    int i;
    size_t sum = 0;

    fprintf(stdout,
        "----------------\n"
        "Stats all bytes:\n"
        "----------------\n"
    );
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        sum += cc[i];
        if (cc[i]) {
            if (isprint(i))
                fprintf(stdout, "%c   : %d\n", i, cc[i]);
            else
                fprintf(stdout, "0x%02x: %d\n", i, cc[i]);

        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Total: %u bytes.\n", sum);
}

void print_stats_alpha(unsigned int cc[256])
{
    int i;
    size_t sum = 0;

    fprintf(stdout,
        "------------------\n"
        "Stats alpha bytes:\n"
        "------------------\n"
    );
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        if (cc[i] && isalpha(i)) {
            sum += cc[i];
            fprintf(stdout,
                "%c: %d\n",
                (char)i, cc[i]
            );
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Total: %u alpha bytes.\n", sum);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fh;
    unsigned int cchar[256] = {0};
    int c;

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fh = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }


    while ((c = getc(fh)) != EOF) {
        ++cchar[c];
    }

    fclose(fh);

    print_stats(cchar);

    print_stats_alpha(cchar);

    return 0;
}
```